# Gray line below header in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my Angular program, there's a gray line right below the header of my table, I tried to inspect it and couldn't figure out what was causing it at all. Here's a bootply of my table: https://www.bootply.com/cA4iIlnsIm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `.table>thead>tr>th` has a border bottom set to #ddd of 1px in `bootstrap.css` you can use the following code in you css to remove it.

```
.table>thead>tr>th{
  border-bottom:0; 
}
```